# With a large number of ignored tags, editing them becomes a hassle

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, ignored-tags

Editing ignored tags can be cumbersome when you have a lot of them already.

If you would be so kind to take a look at the following. My front page looks like this:

[image: as usual]

When I proceed to click "edit" on the right of **Ignored Tags**...

[image: clicked edit]

... I have to scroll all the way to the bottom of the page to find a small add box using my trusty scrollbar or scroll wheel. Both of which take ages:

[image]

To add to my agony, I normally middleclick to make the autoscroll option appear. Then I can just move my mouse down and it will go to the place fast. But if I middle click to the right of the list of ignored tags, the add box dissappears. So I have to use the scroll wheel or scroll bar instead, which takes forever.

Could something be done to address this issue?

Comment: bros. it took me hour to write this and why all -1? :'(

Comment: This might be Meta, but we still value a well written post. Saying that things "suck" is not the most constructive approach. The whole "bros" opener is unnecessary at the very least. (Last I checked, you were not my bro, though I will check once again) And proper capitalization is always welcome. I've made some edits which should stop the worst of the downvotes.

Comment: @Dude, I would suggest you ignore `*` instead of all these tags, it will achieve roughly the same result and avoid clobbering the page.

Comment: Also: you can get rid of [tag:gsm0338], it no longer exists.

Comment: That's not a bug. Think of creative way to address this issue and you might get upvotes when turning it into feature request.

Comment: In other words instead of a bug, this is a feature request to move the Add box to the top of the list of tags?

Answer (score 11):

I will give a way around which should suffice.

Suppose you found a tag you don't like and want to ignore. Whenever hovering over the tag name, **you can add it to your ignored tags list from within that box**:

> [image]

Two clicks on the star and it's all done:

> [image]

Comment: **thanks** bro. i didn't no about this!!

Comment: @DudeBro Something tells me you didn't get anything out of my edit, did you?

Comment: @Dude now you know, that's what Meta is for... if you ask properly you will get better feedback and less downvotes in the future so better listen to Bart here. :)

Answer (score 10):

The ignore tags feature was never meant to be stuffed with so many tags.

You *can* use wildcards here, for example you can ignore `[facebook*]`. Or just ignore `*` and favorite the tags you are interested in here.

Or just use the tag-specific active questions feed.

Comment: today I learned about wildcards

Comment: oh cool now i can replace my 10 visual-studio ignores with visual-studio*

Comment: @DudeBro looks like that, bro

Comment: @DudeBro: You can also ignore however many `visual-whatever` tags with `visual-*` (or even `visual*`).